# Is it possible to make this shell script faster?

Tags: python, shell, unix

I have a task of creating a script which takes a huge text file as an input. It then needs to find all words and the number of occurrences and create a new file with each line displaying a unique word and its occurrence.

As an example take a file with this content:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.   
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I need to create a file which looks like this:

```
1 AD
1 ADIPISICING
1 ALIQUA
...
1 ALIQUIP
1 DO
2 DOLOR
2 DOLORE
...
```

For this I wrote a script using `tr`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT=$1
OUTPUT=$2
if [ -a $INPUT ]
then
    tr '[:space:][\-_?!.;\:]' '\n' < $INPUT | 
        tr -d '[:punct:][:special:][:digit:]' |
        tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' |
        sort |
        uniq -c > $OUTPUT
fi
```

What this does is split the words by space as the delimiter. If the word contains `-_?!.;:` I break them into words again. I remove the punctuations, special characters and digits and convert the entire string to uppercase. Once this is done I sort it and pass it through `uniq` to get it to the format I want.

Now I downloaded the bible in txt format and used it as the input. Timing this I got:

```
scripts|$ time ./text-to-word.sh text.txt b     
./text-to-word.sh text.txt b  16.17s user 0.09s system 102% cpu 15.934 total
```

I did the same with a Python script:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1])

c = Counter()

for line in file.readlines():
    c.update([re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', l).upper()
            for l in chain(*[re.split('[-_?!.;:]', word)
                    for word in line.split()])])

file2 = open('output.txt', 'w')
for key in sorted(c):
    file2.write(key + ' ' + str(c[key]) + '\n')
```

When I executed the script I got:

```
scripts|$ time python text-to-word.py text.txt
python text-to-word.py text.txt  7.23s user 0.04s system 97% cpu 7.456 total
```

As you can see it ran in **7.23s** compared to the shell script which ran in **16.17s**. I have tried with bigger files and always Python seems to triumph. I have a few questions to the senario above:

1. Why is the Python script faster given that the shell commands are written in C? I do realize the shell script may not be the optimum one.
2. How can I improve the shell script?
3. Can I improve the Python script?

To be clear I am not comparing Python to shell scripts. I am not trying to start a flame war or do not need answers in any other language comparing itself to be faster. Using the UNIX philosophy of piping small commands to do a task, how do I make the shell script faster?

Comment: I'd suggest change the title to something like "Is it possible to make this shell script faster ?", using the so different python script only as comparison point. This would eliminate the risk of useless and off-topic discussions about the differences between python and shell.

Comment: I don't think that the \*nix philosophy of using many small commands that do a single task well is in place because it is most *efficient*.  The reason that it is in place is because with the tools we have, you can accomplish so much and save yourself a lot of time developing a new program for a simple task.

Comment: Python is written in C, too. Being "written in C" isn't enough to make things fast -- intervening layers (and all the reading/writing to and from pipelines) have overhead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An important point here is probably inter-process I/O. The Python script has all data in memory, so no I/O happens while it processes the data.

Also note that Python isn't slow as such. Most functionality in Python is implemented in C.

The shell script has to start 5 processes and each of them has to read the whole text from `stdin` and write the whole text to `stdout` four times.

There might be a way to make the Python script a bit faster: You can read the whole text into a single string, then remove all punctuation, split words and then count them:

```
text = file.read()
text = re.sub(r'[.,:;-_]', '', text)
text = text.upper()
words = re.split(r'\\s+', text)
c = Counter()
c.update(words)
```

That would avoid the overhead of several nested loops.

As for the shell script: You should try to reduce the number of processes. The three `tr` processes could probably be replaced with one call to `sed`.

Comment: My guess is that the most important factor is the overhead of launching many subprocesses.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: No; there are just five processes involved in total. Starting them will take way less than 1s and his scripts runs for 16s.

Comment: I didn't want to read the entire file into memory as I would be having a much bigger file.

Comment: How big? Hundreds of gigabytes? If the file size is around 100MB, reading the whole file into RAM is still feasible. If the file is really too huge, try to read larger blocks (i.e. several lines) and process them in one go.

Comment: I don't think the above is true.  The file is read once and written once by each process, in a pipeline.  So, 4K chunks of the file pass through the pipeline all the way to sort, who collects the results and writes out the sorted results.  You could proabably speed it up by giving sort the -S option with an amount of memory more similiar to the size of the file.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, you are right. The file will probably be in a few 100s of MB. So it is quite feasible. I will try reading it as chunks though.

Comment: @ers81239 I was also thinking of the same. Quick question is how does the OS work the pipes? Is the file loaded into the memory?

Comment: pipes are 4KB buffers between processes. When data is copied between processes, the OS has first to write the data into the pipe's buffer, then it must flush CPU caches (otherwise the receiver might not see the current memory) and then notify the other process that data is available. When the other process gets the CPU next time, it will start to read the data.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a matter of one language vs another.  Your approach is different.

In Python, you are incrementing a counter for every word as you encounter it, and then iterating your counter to produce the output.  This is going to be O(n).

In bash, you are putting all of your words individually into a long tuple, sorting the tuple, then counting instances.  This is most likely going to be O(nlogn) for the sort.

Comment: The `counter` is still sorted which is at best `O(N*log(N))`

Comment: the n of the counter is less than the N of the long tuple because there are many duplicates

Comment: *  You both have it wrong.  From the Python docs:


  *  A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. 


  *  The time order of the counter is still N because you have to inspect all N elements to get the count of each.  You are right that the memory order of counter is K where K is the number of uniques.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your bash script:

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*/\'$'\n/g'  <$INPUT | sort -f -u >$OUTPUT
```

But the short and right answer to your question is: Because you are using totally different algorithms.

Comment: Thanks but your script does not give me the occurrences and it runs slower. But you are right in pointing out the difference in algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Considering input file to be Input.txt

**Bash script**

```
cat Input.txt | tr [:space:] '\n' | grep -v "^\s*$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
WHINY_USERS=1 awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sub("[,.]","",$i); array[toupper($i)]++ } } END { for (j in array) print array[j], j }' file.txt
```

---

Pseudocode/explanation:

```
## WHINY_USERS=1 enables sorting by keys. A bit of a trick.
## Now loop through each word on each line, removing commas, full-stops,
## adding each word in uppercase to an array.
## Loop through the array printing vals and keys
```

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

a bash solution

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=' -_?!.;\:,'
while read -r line; do
  for word in $line; do
    word=${word//[^[:alpha:]]/}
    [ $word ] || continue
    word=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"$word")
    ((_w_$word++))
  done
done <"$INPUT"
IFS=' '
for wword in ${!_w_*}; do echo "${!wword} ${wword#_w_}"; done > $OUTPUT.v1
```

a perl golf solution

```
perl -nle '$h{uc()}++for/(\w+)/g}{print"$h{$_} $_"for sort keys%h'  $INPUT > $OUTPUT.v2
```